# How to send data from JavaScript to server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function which gets a value from a slider and I need to send it to the server. I call the function which gets the parameter and works fine but the post function is not working inside.

How is it possible to call a jQuery function inside another function? Is there a better way to do this?

```
function process_decision(slider_value) {
        var selectedData = {};
        selectedData['pick_pack_point'] = slider_value;
        selectedData['gameID'] = <?php echo $booxuser->game->id?>;
        selectedData['teamID'] = <?php echo $booxuser->team->id ?>;
        selectedData['roundID'] = <?php echo $booxuser->game->getRoundToBePlotted() ?>;

        $.post('index.php',
            {
                'option': 'com_maximulation',
                'task': 'max_decision_pickpack.pickpack',
                'data': selectedData,
                '<?php echo JSession::getFormToken(); ?>': '1'
            },
            function (response) {
                var response_data = JSON.parse(response);
                document.getElementById("loanResultDiv").innerHTML = response_data['data']['first'];
            },
            'text'
        );
    }
```

Comment: What you mean by _the post function is not working_?!!

Comment: What error are you getting? Of course you can call jquery post from inside a function.

Comment: Is there a javascript-error in the console? What is not working exactly? Can you post the rendered javascript as it is in the html-source so that we can check for syntax errors.

Comment: What are errors you are getting? check the console.

Comment: What is `'text'`?

Comment: convert object to json string  using **JSON.stringify(selectedData)** then try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using jQuery instead of $, if there is another library imported, the $ could be conflicted.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the reputation to comment on that post, but I thought this could be important to mention.